# Scrollable sliding view in Android

Tags: android, view, slide, scrollable

I'd like to create a sliding view showing facebook contacts at the bottom of the screen.

When clicking on the facebook logo, as shown in top image, I'll show a facebook login form, and once logged in, clicking on the facebook logo will slide in/out the view (bottom image shows view after slide out). The view will contain pictures of some selected facebook contacts (not all, say up to 10), so the view should be scrollable to be able to see selected contacts.

I found SlidingDrawer, but it seems it requires two separate children views, one for handle, another for content, while I want one view, with only a selected area shown when slidden in.

Any suggestion on the best way to achieve this?

Thank you

[image: slidemenu1]

[image: slidemenu2]

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be done with a simple ScrollView using the smoothScrollTo method?

[ScrollView.smoothScrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can try by having a LinearLayout with ImageButton(facebook logo) a nd a Galleryview(initially not visible)on click of that button set Visibility of Imagebutton to `Visible.GONE` and Gallery view to Visible